# Prove that an infinite set $A$ with a one-to-one correspondence to $N$ is countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this is what I have come up with: As there exists a one-to-one function from $A$ to $N$, then by definition, $A$ is countable. Since the set $A$ is infinite and countable, then it is countably infinite.

I feel like it is important to mention that I have taken the following as a definition in class: "A set $S$ is countable if there exists an injective function $f$ from $S$ to $N$"

I was wondering if there is anything wrong with my proof since it seems lacking and shallow. I feel like it was too easy to get to that proof and that there's something I'm missing. I considered proving that $f$ is surjective and $A$ is equivalent to $N$ and therefore it is countably infinite, but I had no idea how to start proving that since I have no clue what $f$ or $A$ are.

Comment: We can user $\mathbb N$ to denote the set of natural numbers, which is of course countably infinite (they are called "counting numbers" for a reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right! With that definition of being countable, the proof is simply extremely short. The only thing I might consider adding, is that a one-to-one correspondence (bijection) is in particular injective, and therefore $A$ is countable.